# less-css -- is it possible to get a parent's parent?

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to get a parent's parent?

I tried `& & { }` but that didn't work.

I'm trying to style a child element based on it's grandparent.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Depends on Code Structure, and may Require Some Repetition of Code

You cannot do it directly in most cases (see second example for exception).

**If Grandparent is an element**

This requires some repetition, but does allow for the grandparent to not be the outermost wrapper (so there could be a great grandparent).

***LESS***

```css
grandparent {  
  /* grandparent styles */
  parent {
    /* parent styles */
    child {
      /* child styles */
    }
  }
  &.specialGrandpa {
    child {
      /* child styles with special Grandpa */
    }
  }
  &.specialGrandma {
    child {
      /* child styles with special Grandma*/
    }
  }
}
```

***CSS Output***

```css
grandparent {
  /* grandparent styles */    
}
grandparent parent {
  /* parent styles */    
}
grandparent parent child {
  /* child styles */    
}
grandparent.specialGrandpa child {
  /* child styles with special Grandpa */    
}
grandparent.specialGrandma child {
  /* child styles with special Grandma*/    
}
```

**If Grandparent is a class, ID, etc., and is the *outermost* wrapper**

No repetition involved here, but you cannot have a `great grandparent` in the mix. Also this is only for LESS 1.3.1+ version (earlier version incorrectly add a space):

***LESS***

```css
.grandparent {  
  /* grandparent styles */
  .parent {
    /* parent styles */
    .child {
      /* child styles */
      .specialGrandparent& {
          /* child styles with special grandparent*/
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***CSS Output***

```css
.grandparent {
  /* grandparent styles */    
}
.grandparent .parent {
  /* parent styles */   
}
.grandparent .parent .child {
  /* child styles */    
}
.specialGrandparent.grandparent .parent .child {
  /* child styles with special grandparent*/   
}
```

This code works by appending to the "front" of the grandparent selector, so that is why the grandparent must be a class, ID, or other selector itself.

**Addendum**

Based on comment about desire to have a red background when the `span` is empty. This does not put the background on the parent, but "fakes" it using the child.

```
span:empty:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: -10px;
    left: -1px;
    bottom: -10px;
    display: block;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Trying to do what you're suggesting...but it doesn't work: http://fiddlesalad.com/less/not-empty-parent-selector/  -- note the last less rule. I'm trying to style the parent div with background of red when its child span is not empty.

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to do something CSS cannot do, and a preprocessor like LESS will not help (since all it does is produce valid CSS). LESS, being a preprocessor, has no idea whether the `span` is empty or not (the processing is done _before_ it is served to the browser; it has no knowledge of the state of the html), and [CSS cannot affect a parent element based off the state of a child element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector). You need to use javascript to do what you want.

Comment: @chovy: However, a work around is to use an `span:empty:after` styled to apply the background. Code given as addendum to my answer.

Comment: Not sure what span:empty:after gets me vs. what I had. But I see I cannot write a rule based on an ancestor...so I'll have to use JS at runtime.

Comment: @chovy: I have not used "fiddlesalad.com" before, and could not figure out how to get it to save. But if you plug the `span:empty:after` code into the place of your non-working code, you will see what it gets you (a red background to the `div` when the `span` is empty).

Answer (score 7):

You cannot traverse arbitrarily up the DOM with less selectors. Use javascript instead.

The `&` in less stands for declared selector one level up. A shortcut for already defined rule. As opposed to what you allegedly seek.

Answer (score 6):

According to LESS's [parent selectors feature](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature), it's possible to *change selector order* by putting the `&` *after* the items in your nest, thereby accessing the item's parent's parent.

**LESS code:**

```
span {
  color:red;
  h6 & {
    color:white;
    div & {
      color:blue;
    }
  }
}
```

**CSS result:**

```
span {
  color: red;
}
h6 span {
  color: white;
}
div h6 span {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Better solution I think !

Answer (score 2):

You can use a mixin, then you can pass variables to it based on grandparent selector specifics.

Example:

```
ul {
    .color-links(@color) {
        li a { // any link inside a child li
            color: @color;
        }
    }
    &.red {
        .color-links(#ff0000);
    }
    &.green {
        .color-links(#00ff00);
    }
}
```