# Simplifying Repetitive LESS

Tags: less, lessphp

I am creating a themeing system for a WordPress network that supports multiple layout themes that can support color schemes for a variety of universities.  To do so, I periodically compile a LESS file (using lessphp) with school-specific variables and essentially use it as a library of helper classes in the themes.

Each school has 3 colors defined in LESS as: `@primary`, `@secondary` and `@tertiary`.  The method is straightforward and functional but requites a lot of repetition in the code.   For example:

```
//Modifier Classes
  .primary-lighter-text {
      color: lighten(@primary,20);
  }
  .sec-lighter-text {
      color: lighten(@secondary,20);
  }
  .tert-lighter-text {
      color: lighten(@tertiary,20);
  }
//Backgrounds
  .primary-bg {
      background-color: @primary;
  }

  .sec-bg {
      background-color: @secondary;
  }

  .tert-bg {
      background-color: @tertiary;  
  }

//Borders
  .primary-border{
      border-color: @primary;
  }
  .sec-border {
      border-color: @secondary;
  }
  .tert-border {
      border-color: @tertiary;      
  }
```

Nothing complicated from a LESS standpoint, but if I want to add a new helper class, I have to create 3.  Is there a more succinct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify it by making use of array loops. All you have to modify in case of a new addition would be to modify the array variables at the end.

```css
.loop-column(@index) when (@index > 0) { /* Recursive Mixin with Guard condition. Mixin is processed only when the condition is satisfied */
  .loop-column(@index - 1); /* Call the mixin again with a decremented counter */
  @ctype:  extract(@type, @index); /* Extract the type value corresponding to the index from the array */
  @color:  extract(@colors, @index); /* Extract the color value corresponding to the index from the array */

  /* Form and Output the necessary classes and properties */
  .@{ctype}-lighter-text { /* Selector interpolation to dynamically form the selector */
    color: lighten(@color,20);
  }
  .@{ctype}-bg {
    background-color: @color;
  }
  .@{ctype}-border{
    border-color: @color;
  }  
}

.loop-column(length(@type));

@type: primary, sec, tert; /* The color types array */
@colors:#fff, #777, #000; /* The color value array for each type */
/* If required the colors can be kept as separate variables also. Refer 2nd demo. */
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/BoeGw) | [**Demo 2**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/uxgEH)

**Update:** (Based on comments from [Andrew Cafourek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2395464/andrew-cafourek) and [seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2712740/seven-phases-max))

Since LessPHP is outdated, the following line should be added and the `length(@type)` should be replaced with the actual count.

```
.loop-column(0) {};
.loop-column(4);
```

Comment: Just spent some time reading up on recursive loops .  They documentation makes them look terrifying but with an example to walk through, they start to make a lot more sense.

Only trouble I'm hitting is that @index won't decrement.  When I try to compile via lessphp, I received the error ``` Error: .loop is undefined: failed at `.loop-column(length(@type)); ``` So, I removed the length function and just used ``` .loop-column(3); ``` which worked.

Now I receive the same error but ``` Error: .loop is undefined: failed at `.loop-column((@index - 1)); ```  Any thoughts on why I'm hitting a snag?

Comment: Same file compiles perfectly using CodeKit - I'll dig into the lessphp docs a bit.

Comment: Ah ha!  Simply adding ``` .loop-column(0) {} ``` before ``` .loop-column(3); ``` did the trick.  Future visitors, see example in [lessphp docs](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#selector_expressions).  It still throws and error if I try and use ``` length(@type) ``` but I can live with that and it all works straight out of the demo from @harry if you are using CodeKit locally

Comment: That's just because `lessphp` is outdated. You can simplify loops further (e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/23551080/2712740 with  similar use-case, notice that the second example there does not use loops at all) but all this requires an up-to-date Less compiler.