# How to loop through set of variables in less?

Tags: css, less

I need to put `@color-1`, `@color-2`, `@color-3`,..  on the place of `@color-@{i}` in loop. What should I put instead?

```
@color-0: rgb(200, 20, 20);
@color-1: ...;
@color-2: ...;
// ...

.generate-headers(5);

.generate-headers( @n, @i: 0 ) when ( @i =< @n ) {
  .widget-header-@{i} {
    width: (@i * 100% / @n);
    background-color: @color-@{i};
    color: overlay( @color-@{i}, @white );
  }
  .generate-headers(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

Comment: I see @color-1 many times. Better explain pseudo code and what is the expected result.

Comment: I tried to use `@color-@{i}` but it didnt work

Comment: Is having separate variables for the colors a must? It would be better to use a array/list (like in [this sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603517/less-declare-variables-using-class-names/25604556#25604556)). If you want to stick to the current approach then you would require something like `@temp: ~"color-@{i}"; background-color: @@temp;`.

Comment: If you really want to reference variables by name (as opposite to more clean "array/list" pattern) you need to use ["Fnord Syntax"](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names). I.e. instead of `background-color: @color-@{i};` use `@color: "color-@{i}; background-color: @@color;`.

Comment: what the first symbol means `~`?

Comment: sorry, @seven-phases-max. didn't see your answer

Comment: @NikTerentyev: `~` is used to output a string without the quotes (just like [`e("a")`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e) would do). But for this case that is also not needed as pointed in seven-phases-max's comment.

Comment: @Nik Terentyev, NP, I guess I commented a few seconds later than you've answered it :) (besides there's a minor typo in my comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found one way:

```
    @color: "color-@{i}";
    background-color: @@color;
```