# How to create a proper class structure?

Tags: css, less

I'm using LESS as css compiler.

Everything works fine, but now I need to create a specific class structure and I'm a bit stuck.

I'd like to have this structure:

```
.default .{color} {.icon-after/.icon-before} {.icon}
```

this is the code that I've done:

```
.default {

  &.disabled {
    background: lighten(@grayBackground, 5%);
    color: lighten(@darkText, 35%);
    cursor: default;
    border: @grayBorder;
    text-shadow: @grayTextShadow;
  }

  &.gray {
    background: @grayBackground;
    color: @darkText;
    border: @grayBorder;
    text-shadow: @grayTextShadow;
    &:hover {
      background: darken(@grayBackground, 5%);
    }
  }

  &.green {
    background: @greenBackground;
    border: @greenBorder;
    color: @lightText;
    text-shadow: @greenTextShadow;
    &:hover {
      background: darken(@greenBackground, 10%);
    }
  }

  &.yellow {
    background: @yellowBackground;
    border: @yellowBorder;
    color: @lightText;
    text-shadow: @yellowTextShadow;
    &:hover {
      background: darken(@yellowBackground, 10%);
    }
  }

  &.blue {
    background: @blueBackground;
    border: @blueBorder;
    color: @lightText;
    text-shadow: @blueTextShadow;
    &:hover {
      background: darken(@blueBackground, 10%);
    }
  }

  &.black {
    background: @blackBackground;
    border: @blackBorder;
    color: @lightText;
    text-shadow: @blackTextShadow;
    &:hover {
      background: darken(@blackBackground, 10%);
    }
  }

  &.red {
    background: @redBackground;
    border: @redBorder;
    color: @lightText;
    text-shadow: @redTextShadow;
    &:hover {
      background: darken(@redBackground, 10%);
    }
  }

  &.icon-before{
    .IconDefaultStyleBefore
  }

  &.icon-after{
    .IconDefaultStyleAfter()
  }
}
```

obviously this doesn't work, as the result is something like this:

```
.default .{color / .icon-after / .icon-before}
```

Any suggestions on how can I obtain my structure?

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**

I'd like to add the classes to the buttons in this order:

- .default( gives the default style )
- {.colours} (so that the background, the border and all colour related properties are setted)
- {.icon-after or .icon-before} so that I can choose if adding the icon before or after with the    proper margin
- {.icon-name} (for example a questionmark or a tick etc)

so, for example, adding this classes:

```
.default .blue .icon-before .tick
```

I will have:

**default blue button with the tick icon before the text**

Hope is now more clear than before.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what doesn't work? By the way you've written your LESS file it's possible to set this on an element: `class="default red icon-after"`. Why not?

Comment: Yeah I know, I will edit the question and explain it better.

Comment: Why do you want this? What's undesirable about your current output?

Comment: This would of been much easier if you posted the css code that you wanted to convert to LESS

Comment: You could simplify this a lot by making use of loops like [here](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/wjIpn). There is a lot of repetitive code in there. Also, check if the structure in that sample meets your needs.

Comment: @Harry your code seams to be a bit complex, do you mind explain it? Sorry but this is my first project using less and i'm not good yet

Comment: I can definitely explain mate, but comments would be too small an area. If that is what you are intending to do then I would add a detailed answer with an explanation.

Comment: I would suggest `extend` but actualy I can't see why you need to put `.icon-after`/`.icon-before` after colors at all. Note that `.default.icon-after` selector will match `<whatever class="default anything icon-after">` just fine.

Comment: I think so, I'm playing with it and I think is what i really need, whit a better optimization as well.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603517/less-declare-variables-using-class-names/25604556#25604556) has a bit of explanation on something similar with loops. I have also added some comments to explain the code in that demo that I gave above. And seven-phases-max definitely has a point in his comment.

Comment: @user3760661: Did that help? Are you comfortable with me making that as an answer?

Comment: @Harry yes. With your example and the answer you mentioned I was able to do it. Thanks a lot.
Make it in a question so that I can choose you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required structure can be achieved as shown in the below example. The code can be simplified a lot by using loops (guarded mixins).

**Explanation:**

1. `@colors` - An array list variable which has the list of colors required for the element.
2. `@bckground` - Another array list variable which holds the required background color for each color class declared in the `@colors` list.
3. `e(extract(@colors, @index))` and `extract(@bckground, @index)` - Extract functions are used to fetch the color name and background color value corresponding to the index of each array iteration (similar to `colors[i]`). `e()` function is used to extract the color values without the quotes.
4. `&.@{color}` - Selector interpolation to form the selector value. `&` is the parent selector and `@{color}` is the name of the color from the `@colors` list variable.
5. `length(@colors)` - The no. of color items present in the `@colors` array list variable. This is passed to the loop function to tell the Less Compiler as to how many times the loop should be executed.

```js
@colors: "red","green","black","blue","gray"; 
@bckground: #AAA, #0F0, #00F, #000, #F00;

.loop-colors(@index) when (@index > 0){ // loop to generate rules for each color
   .loop-colors(@index - 1);// call for the next iteration
   @color: e(extract(@colors, @index));
   @bgColor: extract(@bckground, @index);

   &.@{color}{
      background: @bgColor; //set background
      /* all other props */

      &:hover {
          background: darken(@bgColor, 5%);
      }

      &.icon-before{
          .IconDefaultStyleBefore;
      }

      &.icon-after{
          .IconDefaultStyleAfter();
      }
   }
}

.default{
    .loop-colors(length(@colors));
}
```

**Note:** As seven-phases-max mentioned in his comment, we are essentially generating a selector structure like `.default.red.icon-before`. Such a selector would essentially mean the same element has all the three classes and so even if it is specified like `.default.icon-before.red` it wouldn't make any difference but I assume that you are trying to make a more readable structure (like ***a default red button with an icon-before***).

Comment: I've another question, I wrote it here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863565/less-loops-set-result-as-after-and-before-content
If you'd like to help even for this would be great.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
.default{
  [...]    

  &.gray, &.black, [...every color...] {
    .icon-before{
      [...]
     }
  }
}
```

EDIT: or if you need a different .icon-before for every color you have to insert it one by one:

```
.default{
 [...]

     &.gray{
     [...]
         .icon-before{
          [...]
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: I can't do like this, as all the colours are different

Comment: Then insert .icon-before{[...]} to every color:
&.black {
    background: @blackBackground;
    border: @blackBorder;
    color: @lightText;
    text-shadow: @blackTextShadow;
    &:hover {
      background: darken(@blackBackground, 10%);
    }
   .icon-before{[...]}
  }

Comment: There's not a quicker way to do it? Cause I will be able to add colours and icon without having to add every time a new class and icon into every colour

Comment: Do you mean something like this? [link](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature)

Comment: @ersoma you can edit your answer instead of posting new code to comments