# Less and conditional parent selector

Tags: css, less

I have a less structure just like this one:

```
.main1,
.main2,
.main3,
.main4{
    & .test1{
       background-color: #f00;
    }

    & .test2{
       background-color: #ff0;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to modify the `background-color` according to the current parent element? For example for `.main1` I would like *#f00* as background, and for `.main2` instead, *#ff0*.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at [less-css — is it possible to get a parent's parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286742/less-css-is-it-possible-to-get-a-parents-parent)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to specify parent selector inside the child one (see [Changing Selector Order](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-changing-selector-order)), e.g.:

```less
.test {
   .main1 & {background-color: red}
   .main2 & {background-color: blue}
}
```

Though it's (even if less verbose) often much less readable and more hindered if compared to just plain straight-forward code:

```less
.main1 .test {background-color: red}
.main2 .test {background-color: blue}
```